# compare arrays using .some()

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i am trying to compare 2 arrays to see if their contents are the same, see example below

```
var array1 = [0,2,2,2,1]
var array2 = [0,2,2,2,3]
```

i want to compare those 2 arrays using the some method 
so i will write a function that returns true if some of the numbers are in both arrays.

i have used the method perfectly fine on one array trying to find a particular value

```
function testArray(){
 var bool = array1.some(function(value){
   return value ===1;
 });
}
console.log(bool)
```

but how to use it for 2 arrays?  any help is appreciated

Comment: I would suggest to use an utility library like Underscore/Lodash

Comment: should `[0,2,2,2,1]` be considered the same as `[0,1,2,2,2]` ? your question is a bit vague "contents are the same"

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array1) === JSON.stringify(array2)` can tell you as well if both arrays are equal or not

Comment: so it tests if they are the same and if they are returns true and if not it returns false. so in my example SOME of the numbers ARE the same so i should get "true" returned

Comment: No it tests the whole array, not only a few elements of it

Answer (score 0):

A solution with [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The **every()** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The **some()** method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

for the same task. Please watch the bangs!

```js
var array1 = [0, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    array2 = [0, 2, 2, 2, 3];

function compareEvery(a1, a2) {
    if (a1.length !== a2.length) { return false; }
    return a1.every(function (a, i) {
        return a === a2[i];
    });
}

function compareSome(a1, a2) {
    if (a1.length !== a2.length) { return false; }
    return !a1.some(function (a, i) {
        return a !== a2[i];
    });
}

document.write(compareEvery(array1, array2) + '<br>');
document.write(compareEvery(array1, array1) + '<br>');

document.write(compareSome(array1, array2) + '<br>');
document.write(compareSome(array1, array1) + '<br>');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test if two arrays contains the same value, you can use `some` in combination with `indexOf`:

```
function containsSameValue(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.some(function(value) {
        return arr2.indexOf(value) > -1;
    });
}

var array1 = [0, 2, 2, 2, 1];
var array2 = [0, 2, 2, 2, 3];

containsSameValue(array1, array2); // true
containsSameValue([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]); // false
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this approach

```
function compare(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i].compare) { 
            if (!arr1[i].compare(arr2[i])) return false;
        }
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var array1 = [0, 2, 2, 2, 1];
var array2 = [0, 2, 2, 2, 3];
compare(array1, array2);
```